# How to kill an open process on node.js?

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-xp, kill-process

I'm trying to set up a build-system for Node.js on sublime, so I can press F7 to call "node" on the openned file. The problem is that the process is then open forever, so, the second time I use F7 I get an add-in-use.

Is there a way I can kill the openned "node.exe" process from node.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop all instances of node.js server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790910/stop-all-instances-of-node-js-server)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the following set of commands to identify the process running on a given port and to termiate it from the command line

```
   sudo fuser -v 5000/tcp // gives you the process running on port 5000
```

It will output details similar to the one shown below

```
                        USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
   5000/tcp:            almypal     20834 F.... node
```

Then use

```
   sudo fuser -vk 5000/tcp
```

to terminate the process. Check once again using

```
   sudo fuser -v 5000/tcp
```

to ensure that the process has terminated.

On Windows you could use the following steps

```
  C:\> tasklist // will show the list of running process'

  Image Name        PID Session Name    Session#    Mem Usage
  System            4   console                 0   236 K
  ...
  node.exe         3592 console                0    8440 k
```

Note the PID corresponding to your node process, in this case 3592. Next run taskkill to terminate the process.

```
  C:\> taskkill /F /PID 3592
```

Or /IM switch

```
  C:\> taskkill /F /IM node.exe
```

Comment: Great answer but... and for Windows?

Comment: Well just noticed not exactly what I was asking for but the commands can be used from node.js and if you change them a little (from process id to proccess name) it does what I asked, so this is the best answer I got.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only command that is working on cloud9 IDE to kill node.js process

Comment: for windows its much simpler that this, simply open task manager and sort by name and `end task` node.js process

Comment: taskkill in windows requires admin rights to run. How can we do it within the npm script??

Answer (score 3):

From within Node.js:

```
var die = function(quitMsg)
{
    console.error(quitMsg)
    process.exit(1);
} 

die('Process quit');
```

There are certain [methods available](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) for exiting that are only available for POSIX (i.e. not Windows) that will exit a process by its process id.

Also, note that you might be able to send a kill() signal using this method, which does not say it isn't available for Windows:

```
process.kill(pid, [signal])
```

Comment: But how do I know the pid of the other running node.exe?

Comment: @Dokkat `console.log('This process is pid ' + process.pid);` will print the pid from the other Node.exe, then you execute the new one with a command line argument of that process's pid, and in the new script you send `SIGTERM` to the pid you have in `argv`.  All of the information is available in that link above.

Comment: @Viclib if you are still interested, I actually ran into this specific problem, and using `process.kill(pid, [signal])` was all I needed. I can give more info if you'd like.

Comment: @BlazeBiker fortunately, I actually managed to kill the process during those 4 years. Nether less, I'm sure some future readers would be glad to learn your findings as an answer to this question!

Comment: Just to add additional detail, I also posted my findings below in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36179604/2831961

Answer (score 3):

If you want to kill all processes than:

```
sudo killall -9 node
```

If you want to kill process on selected port than:

```
sudo kill sudo lsof -t -i:3100
```

That was port `3100`

Answer (score 0):

If sublime you say is sublimeText plugin, I have the same issue, and send TCP server a message 'shutdown' from python code, then

**app.js**

```
 TCPserver
        .on('connection', function(socket)
        {
            socket.pipe(require('through')
                (function(data)
                { //----------------------------
                    if (data.toString() === 'shutdown')
                    {
                        process.exit();
                    }
                    //--------------------------
                }));
            socket.end();
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what @Alex W said, you can send a kill signal to the process so long as you have its process ID, or PID using the following node function:

`process.kill(pid, [signal])`

In my case, I had the PIDs readily available as I was spawning `child_process().spawn.pid`. I have tested it and it does work on Win 7 x64.