# Stop all instances of Node.js server

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, express, port

I have started a Node server through the plugin of an IDE. Unfortunately, I cannot use the IDE's terminal. So I tried to run the script from the command line.

This is the problem - I am using the Express module and my app is listening some port (8080). When I start the app from the command line, it throws this error:

```
events.js:71
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at HTTPServer.Server._listen2 (net.js:910:14)
    at listen (net.js:937:10)
    at HTTPServer.Server.listen (net.js:986:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\node\chat\app.js:5:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Even though I am not very sure what this error could be I assumed that it's because the app is listening on a port which is already in use. So I did:

```
netstat -an
```

I can see

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

It's because the Node server is already started when I tried to start it from the IDE.

So I want to know, how can I stop all server instances? Also if you can tell me how to detect what's running on a port and kill it.

Comment: Sorry I dint mention that I am on windows environment. Please post commands that are relevant.
Thanks

Comment: and also you can find the node.js task in your windows taskmanager.
find the progress which name is Node.js:Server-side...and open it's detail info,you will find the pid and detail of your nodejs progress

Comment: This is the one worked for me: https://superuser.com/questions/1183057/tasklist-shows-process-but-taskkill-is-unable-to-kill-it-even-as-admin

Answer (score 676, accepted):

### **Windows Machine:**

Need to kill a Node.js server, and you don't have any other Node processes running, you can tell your machine to kill all processes named `node.exe`. That would look like this:

```
taskkill /im node.exe
```

And if the processes still persist, you can force the processes to terminate by adding the `/f` flag:

```
taskkill /f /im node.exe
```

If you need more fine-grained control and need to only kill a server that is running on a specific port, you can use `netstat` to find the process ID, then send a kill signal to it. So in your case, where the port is `8080`, you could run the following:

```
C:\>netstat -ano | find "LISTENING" | find "8080"
```

The fifth column of the output is the process ID:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       14828
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       14828
```

You could then kill the process with `taskkill /pid 14828`. If the process refuses to exit, then just add the `/f` (force) parameter to the command.

---

### **MacOS machine:**

The process is almost identical. You could either kill all Node processes running on the machine:

```
killall node
```

Or also as alluded to in [@jacob-groundwater's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14791025/58) using `lsof`, you can find the PID of a process listening on a port (pass the `-i` flag and the port to significantly speed this up):

```
$ lsof -Pi :8080
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node     1073    urname   22u  IPv6  bunchanumbershere      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

The process ID in this case is the number underneath the PID column, which you could then pass to the `kill` command:

```
$ kill 1073
```

If the process refuses to exit, then just use the `-9` flag, which is a `SIGTERM` and cannot be ignored:

```
$ kill -9 1073
```

---

### **Linux machine:**

Again, the process is almost identical. You could either kill all Node processes running on the machine (use `-$SIGNAL` if `SIGKILL` is insufficient):

```
killall node
```

Or also using `netstat`, you can find the PID of a process listening on a port:

```
$ netstat -nlp | grep :8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1073/node
```

The process ID in this case is the number before the process name in the sixth column, which you could then pass to the `kill` command:

```
$ kill 1073
```

If the process refuses to exit, then just use the `-9` flag, which is a `SIGTERM` and cannot be ignored:

```
$ kill -9 1073
```

Comment: sorry , How exactly I can use these commands?
process.exit() might be in code? but server is already started. It is likely that it is started with command node app.js but not node-dev app.js.

And "node killall" is not working. Am I doing it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: `process.exit()` in your application causes the NodeJS instance to close. `killall node` in bash would kill all NodeJS instances running on your machine.

Comment: thanks @hexacyanide . I am developing on windows. Does that make killall node an invalid command because I cannot use it from command line.

Comment: Try `taskkill /IM node.exe`. It will kill all processes named `node.exe`.

Comment: I had to use taskkill /F /IM node.exe to make it work, thanks!

Comment: As much as you guys are anal about duplicates and what not. You should really try to update your answer cause technically, what was given is wrong

Comment: These return status code 1 and fail all builds in VSTS. Any way around this?

Comment: For the windows solution with -/f I get "There is no running instance of the task"

Comment: Excellent. For whatever reason a particular app won't close the express server when the terminal is closed, or the batch job is terminated, this was a great help so I didn't need to kill all the other node by guesswork.

Answer (score 135):

Works for Linux, OS X

```
killall node
```

Comment: Easy method but if any other application is running then we have to be more specific.

Comment: does not work for me. `node: no process found` Also when I grep for a node processes which run on the specific port, the process ID has `-` instead of a number itself.

Answer (score 58):

You can use `lsof` get the process that has bound to the required port.

Unfortunately the flags seem to be different depending on system, but on Mac OS X you can run

```
lsof -Pi | grep LISTEN
```

For example, on my machine I get something like:

```
mongod     8662 jacob    6u  IPv4 0x17ceae4e0970fbe9      0t0  TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod     8662 jacob    7u  IPv4 0x17ceae4e0f9c24b1      0t0  TCP localhost:28017 (LISTEN)
memcached  8680 jacob   17u  IPv4 0x17ceae4e0971f7d1      0t0  TCP *:11211 (LISTEN)
memcached  8680 jacob   18u  IPv6 0x17ceae4e0bdf6479      0t0  TCP *:11211 (LISTEN)
mysqld     9394 jacob   10u  IPv4 0x17ceae4e080c4001      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
redis-ser 75429 jacob    4u  IPv4 0x17ceae4e1ba8ea59      0t0  TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)
```

The second number is the PID and the port they're listening to is on the right before "(LISTEN)". Find the rogue PID and `kill -9 $PID` to terminate with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Hi Jacob , please can you edit answer and add windows version because I am  developing on windows. Thank you

Comment: I have no idea how to do it on Windows, sorry Kiran.

Comment: This is a great answer, especially when there are multiple node servers running on different ports. I can easily distinguish the process ID's running on each port.

Comment: lsof cmd not  recognized.

Answer (score 40):

**Windows & GitBash Terminal** 
I needed to use this command inside Windows / Webstorm / GitBash terminal

```
cmd "/C TASKKILL /IM node.exe /F"
```

Comment: This one did it for me. Thanks

Comment: This one did it for me as well. I found it fastest way to kill all node processes on Windows.

Answer (score 26):

if you want to kill a specific node process , you can go to command line route and type:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

to get a list of all node process ids. now you can get your process id(pid), then
do:

```
kill -9 PID
```

and if you want to kill all node processes then do:

```
killall -9 node
```

-9 switch is like end task on windows. it will force the process to end.
you can do:

```
kill -l
```

to see all switches of kill command and their comments.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me in ubuntu

Answer (score 16):

**Linux**

To impress your friends

```
ps aux | grep -i node | awk '{print $2}' | xargs  kill -9
```

But this is the one you will remember

```
killall node
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
taskkill /IM node.exe -F
```

Answer (score 9):

it works fine in windows 10

```
taskkill /f /im node.exe
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Windows, follow this:

1. Open task manager, look for this process:
   [image: Task manager showing Node process - Node.js Server-side JavaScript]
2. Then just right click and "End task" it.
3. That's it, now all the npm commands run form the start.

Answer (score 5):

**Multiplatform, stable, best solution:**

use **[fkill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fkill)** to kill process which is taking your port:

```
fkill -f :8080
```

To install fkill use command: **npm i -g fkill**

Comment: Thanks Dariusz. For anyone stumbling on this in 2021, it's `npm i -g fkill-cli`.

Answer (score 4):

`lsof -Pi :number-of-port` e.g. 3000

then will appear something like that on your terminal

```bash
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    26476 node   30u  IPv6 63828225      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

`kill PID-NUMBER-YOU-WANNA-KILL`

e.g
`kill 26476`

PID stands for Process ID

Answer (score 3):

You could also try:

`killall nodejs`

Answer (score 1):

Am Using windows Operating system.

I killed all the node process and restarted the app it worked.

try

```
taskkill /im node.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

in windows command
Type command blow:

```
taskkill /f /im node.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to kill and restart node server from batch file

```
    @echo off
cd "D:\sam\Projects\Node"
taskkill /IM node.exe -F
start /min cmd /C "node index.js"
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified Windows.  If you want to include this in a bat file, you might not want it to generate an error if the process is not running.

So, to prevent "ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found.", you can add a filter:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM node.exe /FI "PID gt 0"
```