# How to modify IP & port use react-native Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I used the react-native Android demo project AwesomeProject and within the project I executed:

```
react-native start
```

In a second terminal:

```
react-native run-android
```

To start webserver and install the Android APK. The default webserver configuration is localhost:8081, how can I modify the webserver port, and how do I update recording of the IP & Port in Android project.

**Edit:**

I just found out that can modify ip address in Android debug setting, it seems "getDebugServerHost" is a private API, does Facebook provide any API to change ip&port?

Comment: Please check my answer at [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54419084/3932166).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** See [Tomty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347636/258482) for the current recommended way to do this in 2019.

Unfortunately, the port is currently (2015/09/23) hardcoded. I believe this will be changed in time as it already has an Issue raised from a high level contributor to the project.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2704

Comment: Thanks. We now just only can modify the url but not port through modify debug_http_host SharedPreferences value.

Comment: Further update: Now the port can also be changed using debug_http_host.

Comment: @Tomty Please can you give a little more insight on how or where to use debug_http_host?

Comment: @bozzmob Added a separate answer elaborating on that. Please let me know if anything's still unclear.

Answer (score 11):

As OP commented on MossP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32736532/3412775), this can now be achieved using the `debug_http_host` shared preference (see [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2727) issue).

So, if you wanted to use, say, port 8082, you could add an `onCreate` method to your `MainActivity.java` file, which might look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);

    SharedPreferences preferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    preferences.edit().putString("debug_http_host", "localhost:8082").apply();
}
```

*Of course not forgetting to import `android.content.SharedPreferences`, `android.os.Bundle`, and `android.preference.PreferenceManager`.*

This would make your app try to access the packager at the desired port instead of 8081.

Then you'd just make sure to start the packager with `--port 8082` (as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html#using-a-port-other-than-8081)), and you should be all set.
(Unless you happen to be using Nuclide, which is a whole other [story](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/708)).

Note that up until React Native 0.46, this would only allow one to *run* the app successfully, but still didn't make it possible to actually attach a *debugger* on a non-standard port. As of React Native 0.46, attaching a debugger [should also work](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/28748f165b3d8a3a8e9567eb2cfe949cc565b715).

Comment: This wasn't asked specifically so I didn't want to reference it in the answer itself, but note also that you can even make the port configurable at build with gradle's buildConfigField, though that can get a bit more complicated.

Comment: I think it is acceptable that answers contain side-notes like this even if they don't answer something that is specifically asked. But of course the answers should answer what is specifically asked and adding on top of that is fine

Comment: This is useful when your target Android device doesn't have a functioning Menu button.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small work around for this. Anyone running this on a physical device(*or even otherwise*) can restart their adb session using a different port.

eg.

```
react-native start --port=1234
```

On a different cmd/terminal window.

```
react-native run-android
```

After which I am greeted by these messages.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 22.589 secs
Running C:\SDK/platform-tools/adb -s VY0025160560725694 reverse tcp:8081 
tcp:8081
```

This runs it on default reverse port of 8081, which is blocked by McAfee.

**Work around:**

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:1234
```

Try it out. It works for me.

**Note:** You may have to kill and re-open the app.

Currently I am unable to provide an answer for an emulated device since I do not have one installed on my system. But the symantics should be similar.

<s>**Note**: This *may* break automatic code updates using watchman.</s>

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu,

> You can access the developer menu by shaking your device or by
>   selecting "Shake Gesture" inside the Hardware menu in the iOS
>   Simulator. You can also use the ⌘D keyboard shortcut when your app is
>   running in the iOS Simulator, or ⌘M when running in an Android
>   emulator. Alternatively for Android, you can run the command adb shell
>   input keyevent 82 to open the dev menu (82 being the Menu key code).

So on iOS device shake it, on iOS emulator press control D, on Android emulator control M, on Android device do `adb shell input keyevent 82`

Then in the menu that opens, go to **Dev Settings**, **debug server & host port for device**, and edit the IP and port.

ps: will only work for non production

Comment: No such menu item in the menu. How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac :

1. go To Wifi
2. Open network preferences
3. Wi-Fi is connected to {wifi name} and has the IP address {xxx.xxx.x.x}.
4. Get your ip address .
5. Go to application on devices
6. go to Dev Setting
7. Tap to Debug server host & port for device
8. Fill your IP address and port is 8081 (example ipaddress:8081) .

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of Tomty's answer. Check out an example project [here](https://github.com/nick-bull/react-native-debug-address-exemplar):

```
npm i @nick-bull/react-native-debug-address

# DEBUG_HOST=127.0.0.1:8081 npx react-native start --port 8081
# or, equivalently
DEBUG_PORT=8081 npx react-native start --port 8081

npx react-native run-android --port 8081
```