# React native change listening port

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react native android and having face issues to deploy the app on an android device.
When I run

> react-native start, it won't start dev server on port `8081`

[image]

I have tried a few options mentioned at:

1. https://reactnative.dev/docs/troubleshooting
2. Tried to stop the process running at port number 8081, but no success

My question is that can we change the React Native dev server port from 8081 (which is a default in android however the same we can change in ios from AppDelegate.m file) to something else or any other approach

Your responses will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Dear Vikram, your question is so important and trend, because of updating React Native, every solution can change, for the current version, the marked post is not working yet, so I add a new solution [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63683065/6877799). please check it out, and if it is the correct answer and you desire to mark it to guide new visitors.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Not sure if this is documented or not[1], you can specify the port via a CLI argument, like this:

```
react-native start --port 9988
```

I found it in the source code, and it worked on my local machine :)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/server/server.js#L30

---

[1] This is now documented here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting#using-a-port-other-than-8081

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick, its working. I am able to change port number

Comment: OMG, thank you ! Have been struggling with this for the past 2 hours. Why is this not documented anywhere?!?!

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The port on windows is hardcoded.

Comment: @AdrianSicaru where did you see that?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735466/how-to-modify-ip-port-use-react-native-android

Comment: @AdrianSicaru the issue seems to be closed (and fixed) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2704

Comment: It is documented now. at any rate: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi (under "Running packager on a non-standard port").

Comment: Though @patrick answer is correct but you will have to write that line every time you need to start the server. Here is a permanent solution if you like. https://github.com/nikhil-thakkar/react-native-patch

Answer (score 15):

I know it is late but FYI, there is also another way where you can change your port permanently.

Go to your_app\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\server.js and change the port 8081 to 8088

which will be something like this

```
    ...
      module.exports = {
      name: 'start',
      func: server,
      description: 'starts the webserver',
      options: [{
        command: '--port [number]',
        default: 8088,
        parse: (val) => Number(val),
      }
     ...
```

**UPDATE TESTED ON RN 0.57:**
1. If you are using custom metro config

```
const config = {
  ...
  server: {
    port: 8088,
  }
  ...
};
```

2. And if you are not then,
Go to your_app\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\util\Config.js

```
const Config = {
   ...
   server: {
      port: process.env.RCT_METRO_PORT || 8088 //changed from 8081
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Changing files in `node_modules` can hardly be called permanent.  Any time you update your dependencies you are going to blow away that change.

Comment: This works for react-native start but for react-native run-ios still pointing to 8081. Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: @YugandharPathi , this is issue is still running on ios, you can track this issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14113). For android I updated the **debug server host & port for device setting** in genymotion and it worked. Give it a try for ios.

Comment: Here is a permanent solution if you like. https://github.com/nikhil-thakkar/react-native-patch

Comment: I changed all 8081 to 8088. But doesn't work for me. Still got the same error.

Answer (score 13):

run metro-bundler server with specified port eg. "8089"

```
react-native start --port 8089
```

build iOS and Android package which listens to above port

**iOS:**. `react-native run-ios --port 8089 --simulator \"iPhone 8\"`

**Android:** `react-native run-android --port 8089`

Change the server and port number in Dev-settings after launching the app on simulator or device.

- **iOS:** `Command + D in Mac and Ctrl + D in windows`

  - Click on *Configure Bundler option*
  - provide host as `localhost` and port as `8089` then apply changes
- **Android:** `Command + M in Mac and Ctrl + M in windows`

  - Click on *Change Bundle Location*
  - change it to `localhost:8089` then press ok

Comment: on android you can use this
npx react-native start --port=6969
Click on Change Bundle Location
change it to localhost:6969 then press ok

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution is:

The below command will build Android or iOS package which will listen to port **1234**

**For iOS**:
`react-native run-ios --port=1234`

For Android
`react-native run-android --port=1234`

If you are using **metro-server** then you can add port under server object like :

`server:{
    port:1234
  }`

**or**

run

`react-native start --port=1234`

Find out more configuration for metro-server here: https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/en/configuration

But requires 0.55 and above.

Comment: This is the complete answer. ^^)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You need to overwrite the `RCT_METRO_PORT` macro variable to ensure your app points to the correct port when running via xcode or `react-native run-ios`. This can be done by opening the Pods project within your workspace, navigating to Build Settings and adding a Preprocessor Macro. For example `RCT_METRO_PORT=7777`, if the port you are using is `7777`.

[image]

Comment: problem is, the pod project is recreated on each `pod install`

Answer (score 4):

After spending a whole day and going through many solutions, a combination of the suggestions helped me resolve this.
Follow the steps given below:

1. Create the project using the command:
   'react-native init [PROJECT_NAME]'
2. Open the project in Xcode and replace all occurrences of "8081" with "8088" and save the changes
3. Open terminal and change the working directory to the above created project directory.
   Use the following command to change the port that react native uses:
   react-native start --port 8088

Once you run this command, you see the following output in the terminal:

[image]

As you can see, this starts the Metro instance. Do not kill the command or the terminal window. Let this process run.

4. Open a new terminal window, change the working directory to the project directory and run the react-native project using the command:

react-native run-ios

Once the project builds successfully on the second terminal, you will see a progress bar indicating the loading of the app bundle in the first terminal window as shown below:

[image]On completion of loading the bundle, the app succesfully launches on the simulator

Hope this helps. Happy coding

Comment: Here is a permanent solution if you like. https://github.com/nikhil-thakkar/react-native-patch

Comment: @nikhil.thakkar Doesn't work. Got error message when install.

Comment: @ZhouHao Please check the github issue. I have added some questions.

Answer (score 3):

```js
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  server: {
    port: 8088,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in the current version of React Native, configs of metro bundler are in the `@react-native-community/cli` and for changing the default PORT of metro bundler we should change the default PORT just by `export` an environment variable by the following command inside the project path:

```
export RCT_METRO_PORT=8590
```

Then in the `ios` folder of your project find the `Pods` folder and inside the `Pods` folder seek `RCTDefines.h` files, there are two of them, inside both of them change the `8081` to `8590`.

Surely, for a test we can run the `echo $RCT_METRO_PORT` and if you see the new PORT `8590`, it is changed now and we can run our project with default commands like `yarn start` and then `yarn ios` or `yarn android`.

**Hint**: for connecting to the React Native Debugger press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and change the `8081` port to `8590`.

Comment: unreliable since the pod file header is recreated on each `pod install`

Comment: @philk, Did you mean my solution isn't still acceptable??

Comment: The RCTDefines.h is recreated on every pod install. Any changes in it are lost. So your solution does not work reliable. Unfortunately the RN creators made too many hardcodes of the port all over the place.

Comment: Yeah, thanks dear @philk, I have seen this really weird issue. why developers like RN folks hardcoded the most important thing. thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: maybe we should file an issue of at their repo?

Comment: @philk, Definitely it has already, But yeah, this is the true way.

Answer (score 2):

Set `RCT_METRO_PORT`, example:

```
export RCT_METRO_PORT=8765
```

Comment: on windows you can use `set` instead of export

Answer (score 2):

```
export RCT_METRO_PORT=8082
react-native start --port $RCT_METRO_PORT
react-native run-ios
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting#using-a-port-other-than-8081

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps :

**Step 1:**

```
vim node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/server.js
```

**Step 2 :**
change the default port - any other port //example -> 8089

**Step 3 :**
go back to the *project* -> and do *npm start*

Comment: The answer just to show everyone that someone uses vim.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [react-native-port-patcher](https://github.com/ktonon/react-native-port-patcher) which replaces the default 8081 port with your desired port number.

Comment: That looks like a really bad idea. Have a look at the acceped answer

Comment: I am running this on Mac. The accepted answer does't work for my case. Even though i run "react-native start --port 9988" and try to run the app by running "react-native run-ios" it tries to run from the default port of 8081 which is already occupied by McAfee. And below is the result.

Connection to localhost port 8081 [tcp/sunproxyadmin] succeeded!

Port 8081 already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2



** BUILD FAILED **

Comment: I am able to run the application only after i have replaced the 8081 port from all the files that use it with some other port. So instead of doing it manually. I was using "react-native-port-patcher" which does the work for us.

Comment: It's a good idea as for now there is no better and more convenient way to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If using yarn-

```
 yarn start --port your port name   // worked for me.
```

**Eg**:-

```
yarn start --port 8082
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the port other than 8081 and running the same in emulator,  i think this link has better working solution :
https://medium.com/@hsuastegui/use-react-native-in-a-different-port-1109db5674d8

Answer (score 0):

When you excute command like

./node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command

to start a debug server,append args like

---port 8082

it works for me in React native 0.53.3.

Answer (score 0):

For windows

correct way is to go to root directory and follow instructions

run cmd as administrator
run `npm start -- --port=8888`

then open another md as administrator in root dir
run `npm run android -- --port=8888`

Answer (score 0):

(Tested on RN 0.72.5)
For iOS, add this to Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
...

# Port fix for metro bundler so when we run 'react-native run-ios --port XXXX' it will use the right port XXXX in Metro server and from the client app
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'].insert(0, "RCT_METRO_PORT=${RCT_METRO_PORT}")
end

...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

If you are using **npm** :-

```
 npm start --port your port name   // worked for me.
```

Eg:-

```
npm start --port 8080
```

If you are using **yarn** :-

```
yarn start --port your port name   // worked for me.
```

Eg:-

```
yarn start --port 3000
```