# react-native cli: error on start up

Tags: react-native

I installed react-native as per the instructions but on

```
$npm start
```

I the following error.

```
ERROR  Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081
Loading dependency graph...
npm ERR! Darwin 17.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 11
npm ERR! TDemo@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-
cli/cli.js start`
```

I guess there is some sort of dependency or conflict, does anyone know how I can figure out what it is?

Comment: [relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315475/react-native-error-packager-cant-listen-on-port-8081) try editing port? `--port=8088`. [Even more relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425754/react-native-error-packager-cant-listen-on-port-8081)

Comment: Ah yes, that did it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess  port 8081 is used somewhere try to kill port and run again

[Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac)

Answer (score 8):

Run the following command to find id of the process which is using port `8081`
`sudo lsof -i :8081`
Then run the following to terminate process:
`kill -9 23583`

Here is how it will look like
[image]