# React- Native by Intellij IDEA

Tags: reactjs, react-native, intellij-idea

How can I run React-Native apps by Intellij IDEA.

[Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylZpa.png)

[when I change port, the same error given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URVSw.png)

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597641/react-native-cli-error-on-start-up

Comment: the same error, still :((

Comment: did you try checking what process is using the port? `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8081`. also, can you check if the issue persists when using basic react native apps generated by cli?

Comment: bro it is running, I change the port 8088 it is work :))

Answer (score 0):

If you are really changing the port, you shouldn't receive the same error. This error generally happens because there is a process already running on this door, if you are using Linux, try fuser -k 8081/tcp, that will kill the process running on that door.

Comment: I am only using macOS :(

Comment: yess, it is run, ı change the port 8088 it is works, thanks so much bro :)))

Answer (score 0):

in my case, just remove the 'start React Native Bundler' before launch task.

some other script will start the bundler too, so 8081 port is in use.