# Change default react-native android port

Tags: android, mongodb, react-native, redux, realm

### **The problem**

I'm developing an app which uses MongoDB realm and Redux. When only redux is in the project, no problem. But then after [debuggin](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) it with realm [installed](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/react-native/install#install-realm-with-npm) errors started happening. Realm is using `port=8083` for its XML requests, while React Native is running by [default](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#method-1-using-adb-reverse-recommended-1) in `port=8081`. So, when realm does its first XML request to [initialize](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/react-native/quick-start#initialize-the-app) the realm app react native crashes.

[image: error in debugger]

### **The troubleshooting**

By looking at the react-native-debugger [documentation](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#getting-started) its possible to change de debugger port. Nice! And then i searched for a way to do the same in react-native. As weird as it sounds, apparently react-native's android port is [hardcoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431052/react-native-change-listening-port) by the `react-native init`, meaning that only the `default 8081` port works. Actually, only the metro server and ios port can be [changed](https://reactnative.dev/docs/troubleshooting#using-a-port-other-than-8081). I requested [support](https://support.mongodb.com/case/00729665) from MongoDB, about changing their `default port to 8081`. But still waiting for an answer.

This is the app  [repository](https://github.com/codeLearnerrr/crudApp)
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the react native app was running in the emulator and it did just fine. Then, i had this idea of turning off the SIM Card internet in the physical device. After doing so, the local wi-fi was used (where the computer was connected as well). Shazam...! That was it. End of story. This was the issue. What bugs me is that the documentation forgot to mention this use case. The nearest i could find was [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi-1)