# How to use RCT_METRO_PORT correctly to change metro bundle port?

Tags: ios, react-native, port, detox, metro-bundler

I would like to run tests on two different builds of iOS, therefore I need the metro bundler to run on two different ports.
But it's about the same repo, so I can't change all the occurrences of 8081.
Also, I can't change manually the port using devtools in iOS Simulator, because it's for e2e tests with Detox, automatics.

I saw here and there that the use of RCT_METRO_PORT could work, but until now I don't success...

So here is the simple question: how do we make use of RCT_METRO_PORT so that the metro bundler runs on another port than 8081, using either a `.env` file or an env variable in `package.json` scripts?

[EDIT]: my question is not only for `react native run ios` but also for building release, like this script `set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myapp -destination name="iPhone 12 Pro" -derivedDataPath ios/build > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can manage different ports for dev and stage env in `package.json`

[DOCS](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md)

```
"scripts": {
  "android:dev": "RCT_METRO_PORT=8081 react-native run-android",
  "android:stage": "RCT_METRO_PORT=9091 react-native run-android",
  "ios:dev": "RCT_METRO_PORT=8081 react-native run-ios",
  "ios:stage": "RCT_METRO_PORT=9091 react-native run-ios",
  "start:dev": "react-native start --port 8081",
  "start:stage": "react-native start --port 9091",
  "build:dev": "export RCT_METRO_PORT=8081 && set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myapp -destination name=\"iPhone 12 Pro\" -derivedDataPath ios/build > /dev/null",
  "build:stage": "export RCT_METRO_PORT=9091 && set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myapp -destination name=\"iPhone 12 Pro\" -derivedDataPath ios/build > /dev/null",
}
```

## OR

```
"scripts": {
  "android:dev": "react-native run-android --port 8081",
  "android:stage": "react-native run-android --port  9091",
  "ios:dev": "react-native run-ios --port 8081",
  "ios:stage": "react-native run-ios --port  9091",
  "start:dev": "react-native start --port 8081",
  "start:stage": "react-native start --port 9091",
  "build:dev": "export RCT_METRO_PORT=8081 && set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myapp -destination name=\"iPhone 12 Pro\" -derivedDataPath ios/build > /dev/null",
  "build:stage": "export RCT_METRO_PORT=9091 && set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myapp -destination name=\"iPhone 12 Pro\" -derivedDataPath ios/build > /dev/null",

}
```

Comment: I edit my post to say that I'm not looking for only dev mode, but for more than that !

Comment: @arnaudambro I edited my answer, you can use `yarn build:dev` or `yarn build:stage`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63683065/6877799) you must change the default port from environment variable, there are three way

1. **First**: (local env): Install [`react-native-dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv), and configure it on your babel config file. Then add a `.env` file in the root folder of your project and write `RCT_METRO_PORT=8590`. (8590 is sample for alternative port number)
2. **Second**: (global env): Go to your bash/zsh rc file and `export` the environment variable with number 8590 for example:

   ```
   export RCT_METRO_PORT=8590
   ```

   *hint*: if your OS is windows, for second option follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48966524/6877799)
3. **Third**: (inline env): For each of actions you should use `--port 8590`:

   - Metro: `yarn start --port 8590`
   - Android: `yarn android --port 8590`
   - iOS: `yarn ios --port 8590`

***TEST***: run `echo $RCT_METRO_PORT` in your terminal to test 1st and 2nd way to be ensure your env var is set.

***iOS Hint***: For the `ios` folder of your project find the `Pods` folder and inside the Pods folder seek `RCTDefines.h` files, there are two of them, inside both of them change the `8081` to `8590`.

> For connecting to the **React Native Debugger** press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and change the `8081` port to `8590`.