# Automatically set a debug server host & port for device in react-native apps

Tags: debugging, react-native, react-native-debugger

Is there a way to automatically set the Debug server host & port for device in react-native apps?

I have to trigger this menu and set a proxy for my app and I want it to be done automatically when the app is installed. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little package for this because it was driving me nuts. Check it out [here](https://github.com/nick-bull/react-native-debug-address-exemplar):

```
npm i @nick-bull/react-native-debug-address

# DEBUG_HOST=127.0.0.1:8081 npx react-native start --port 8081
# or, equivalently
DEBUG_PORT=8081 npx react-native start --port 8081

npx react-native run-android --port 8081
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

*add to package.json scripts*

```
"android": "react-native run-android --host=<ip-address>:8081"
```

*then to run to start up project*

```
npm run android
```

**Or:**

take a look at this

> [How to modify IP & port use react-native Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735466/how-to-modify-ip-port-use-react-native-android/40347636][1])

Comment: this doesnt work `error: unknown option ``--host`'`