# "Running two copies of Meteor..." error when trying to launch an IOS/ Android app in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I get this error when trying to launch an IOS/ Android app in Meteor how can I solve it?

> Running two copies of Meteor in the same application directory will
>   not work. If something else is using port 3000, you can specify an
>   alternative port with --port .

Comment: Try launching meteor with `meteor --port 5005`

Answer (score 1):

This is because of may be running two copies of Meteor in the same application.

So need to kill the process of node or run in different port for the application

```
killall node

meteor --port 3030
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this happens for a couple of reasons; either you have two copies of Meteor running, or you have orphaned a copy of Meteor (e.g. by closing the command prompt or shell you started it from) and it is still running in the background.

If you have two copies running you can force Meteor to use a different port with the `--port` parameter when you launch meteor, e.g. `meteor --port 5005`.

If you have orphaned an instance of Meteor you will need to kill the node instance that's running it - [this question explains how to stop node instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790910/stop-all-instances-of-node-js-server).