# Node.js server is not stopping on forever stop 0

Tags: javascript, node.js

My case is this:

I am running a node.js server at `domain.com:54321`

The command I use to start the server is:

```
forever start -l forever.log -a -o out.log -e err.log index.js
```

However, there are some cases where our code gets into a high demanding function, causing the script to work very slow or unresponsive. We are trying to optimize it.

In that case, I stop the server, and start a new one if needed, lets say `domain.com:67890`

```
forever stop 0
```

But if I want to start again the recently stopped node.js server `domain.com:54321` (or restart it instead of stopping it) with this, I was expecting the processes to stop and run as fresh and fast again.

The thing that if I start it again, or restart it, it continues to go high on resources. I found out that I need to leave it for a couple of hours to start it again.

My question is, are there any other commands that will make sure that every instance, resource of that server is stopped, so I can start using it again immediately?

Thank you

Comment: Try running 'forever list' and 'sudo forever list' after stopping your service, list needs to be empty

Comment: @AlfredoLanzetta I do this, and they are indeed stopped.

Comment: Try to run `forever.stopAll && forever.cleanUp`. I also suggest you to use PM2 
instead of forever for your project.

Comment: @AlfredoLanzetta is `forever.stopAll` stops all running node.js servers? (I am asking this without testing it first because I will run this in the production)

Comment: yes, i was looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: @AlfredoLanzetta thank you, but I don't really think that `forever stopall` is any different of `forever stop 0` (assuming you have 1 running server)

Comment: Use [`pm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2), it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can stop a Forever daemon using the id of forever running using four different ways:

- index
- id
- uid
- pid

I can see one of the answer to covering the stopping a forever running daemon using pid, I can add for other methods.

List running Forever instances:

`$ forever list`

info:    Forever processes running

```
|data: | index | uid | command          | script      |forever pid|id   | logfile                |uptime        |
|------|-------|-----|------------------|-------------|-----------|-----|------------------------|--------------|
|data: | [0]   |f4Kt |/usr/bin/nodejs   | src/index.js|2131       | 2146|/root/.forever/f4Kt.log | 0:0:0:11.485 |
```

`$ forever stop 0` **index**

`$ forever stop 2146`  **id**

`$ forever stop --uid f4Kt`  **uid**

`$ forever stop --pidFile 2131`  **pid**

Comment: Hello, I don't think that this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure to stop the process you can use the [pid option](https://github.com/foreversd/forever#usage):

```
forever start -l forever.log -a -o out.log -e err.log --pidFile ~/app_pid index.js

forever stop --pidFile ~/app_pid
```

Comment: Hey Victor, is this different from `forever stop 0` ?

Comment: Hello, I don't think that this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Run `forever list` then `forever stop **id**`

Here is a sample output

```
$ forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command                                                  script forever pid   id logfile                          uptime        
data:    [0] 9Xzw ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 300         1111   2312    /home/ec2-user/.forever/9Xzw.log 1:3:20:50.412 
data:    [1] wOj1 npm run-script app-start-dev                                    29500   24978    /home/ec2-user/.forever/wOj1.log 0:0:5:3.433
```

Check your process id and kill

`forever stop 0` OR `forever stop 1` OR `forever stop 2`

Here 0, 1, 2 index of process, `data:[0]`, `data:[1]`

Comment: Hello, I don't think that this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

May be kill all node processes forcefully if that is what you want.

follow this answer to kill all node process : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790921/5055850

Answer (score 0):

check this, if your port are 8000 , it will stop forever

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8000`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me this worked:
forever stopall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).