# How to open compiled Flutter web index.html in browser locally?

Tags: flutter, browser, flutter-web

Running `flutter build web` creates `index.html` file in `/build/web/` along with

```
assets                    icons                     manifest.json
favicon.png               index.html                version.json
flutter_service_worker.js main.dart.js
```

The current flutter channel is beta.

`$ flutter channel`

```
Flutter channels:  
  master  
  dev  
* beta  
  stable
```

`flutter --version`

```
Flutter 1.25.0-8.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8f89f6505b (2 weeks ago) • 2020-12-15 15:07:52 -0800
Engine • revision 92ae191c17
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.2.beta)
```

When I try to open `/build/web/index.html` in the Chrome browser, it shows blank. Is it usual or do I need to install any node packages to make it run?

Note: I followed this doc https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web.

Does it have anything to do with this code in index.html which does not seem to be included in the earlier flutter versions?

```
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to install node.js server from npm to run the website on.

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Change directory to /build/web and run the server on localhost with:

```
npx http-server
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: @SawThinkarNayHtoo np :)

Comment: Hey I hav a issue actually I started server on local host and then I am unable to exit my project from there know i am panicking I am afraid because of hackers and stealers I hav no idea in this area I unfortunately closed the terminal so I am unable to control + c and I don't know how many host are running and how please help me. Asap

Comment: @Lucian closing the terminal stops the http server i guess. You can try solutions suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790910/stop-all-instances-of-node-js-server

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the topic, you can also use python to server it: [Set up a local testing server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server)

```
\[flutter_project]\build\web> python -m http.server
```

or

```
\[flutter_project]\build\web> python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then go to [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000)

Comment: I had to use python3.

`\[flutter_project]\build\web> python3 -m http.server`

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:

1. Download Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) and install it.
2. Open command prompt and type your build/web path like this: `cd C:\Users\YourUSER\Documents\build\web`
3. Type `python -m http.server 8080`  -> This is another port exclusively for your app.
4. Open Edge Browser and type: `http://localhost:8080`
5. Click on the icon button on top right (install yourApp to run on your own page)
   And thats it! You can create a shortcut on your desktop to run automatically!