# How to solve the error: "Address already in use" on a listener server?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I've implemented a NodeJS web application, I've built it with Google Cloud and every time I run the instance I get an error saying "Address already in use port:3030".

It's an application that authenticates the user through Google, so the server listens to receive the confirmation that the user has authenticated correctly.

First, I had the listener port set as 3000 and as I was getting the mentioned error I changed it to 3030 but I'm still getting the same error.
In the Google Cloud Shell, I've run the command "netstat -an" to show all open ports and the 3030 isn't in the list. To clarify, if I run "netstat -an | grep 3030" there is no output.

In addition, I checked in Google Cloud Run there is only one instance of the application running.

Hopefully, someone can give me some clue on how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for running instances. Make sure that there are no other instances of your Node.js application already running and using the same port.

Use the following command to identify and kill any processes using the port:

```
lsof -i :3030
kill -9 <PID>
```

For other cases of stopping instances of Node.js, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790910/stop-all-instances-of-node-js-server).

Comment: Hi, I've used the Google Cloud shell and I've run the first command and even with "sudo" it doesn't return anything. I guess the port is not active and the app is stating that is in use when in fact it finds the port shutdown. I'm trying to understand how to enable one specific port in Google Cloud as the firewall rules look ok (all ports are allowed).