# Error: listen EADDRINUSE in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created javascript build system in sublime using [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qW7cseYJu4)

Then I run server using that code

```
var server = require('http');

function engine(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200,  {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end("Hello");
}

server.createServer(engine).listen(3000);
```

but when I'll make change and for example will change `Hello` to `Hello World`  and refresh browser it doesn't make any sense and when I'm trying rerun (f7) it throws an exception

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1363:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gsiradze\Desktop\nodejs\script1.js:4:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I know that it's because of 3000 port is in use but how can I stop that port an then run the new code?

I'm pretty new at node.js, so feel free to give any suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs Error: listen EADDRINUSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/nodejs-error-listen-eaddrinuse)

Comment: @BenFortune you haven't read my question..

Comment: I sure did. Read the answers in the dupe.

Comment: @BenFortune read and? I too can google. Already found and tried that. it throws same error

Comment: and stop downvote all answer which I'm getting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you run the nodejs implementation?

You could try to use the package [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Now you can start your node application by typing nodemon in the directory.
If you change and save your file now, the server will automatically restart your server.

If you dont want to use nodemon, shut down the server with ctrl+c

Comment: I'm not running it using cmd. it's sublimes js build system

Comment: @George i think you will find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276249/how-to-kill-an-open-process-on-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

`server.createServer(engine).listen(3000);`

that's where you say where port is located, you can change port to any other one.

To rerun your code, I take it you use console you can press ctrl+C to stop process and run it again with node nameOfYoursServerFile.js

Comment: I'm not running it using cmd. it's sublimes js build system

Comment: Then problem could be in js build system I'm not familiar how it work, could you try using console of any sort? cmd, terminal, git bash or node console would do the trick

Answer (score -1):

Find what is the PID of your process on 3000 with `lsof -w -n -i tcp:3000`
Then, just kill it with `kill -9 PID` switching `PID` with the PID returned by the first command.

Comment: So specify in your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
You need to get the PID of node service
You can do that by running this command on your terminal
    ps aux | grep node
it will give you  id of running node process
and the you can use 
    kill -9 <id of node process>
to stop node process and then try again to run your node server
```

Answer (score -1):

Either `Ctrl+C` the foreground process or find your running process's ID by using `pidof node` and then killing it (`kill pid`). Even if you are running with `forever` or in the background some other way, this will work.

Comment: how can I find pidof node? I'm on windows

Comment: On Windows you can use `tasklist | find "node"`.